# PHP script is not uploading images

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload

hi i am having a script which allows user to upload images but it is not uploading the images. everything is fine like rand number etc but the image is not only being uploaded. Following is my image uploading form.

```
    <form action="register.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="regForm" id="regForm" >
        <table width="95%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" class="forms">
           <tr>
               <td>Profile Image<span class="required"><font color="#CC0000">*</font></span> </td>
               <td><input name="user_image" type="file" class="required password" id="user_image"> 
                   <span class="example">Upload your image</span>
                   <input name="doRegister" type="submit" id="doRegister" value="Register">
               </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

And this is register.php

```
<?php
 $path = "user/".time().uniqid(rand()).basename($_FILES['user_image']['name'],'.');
 if($user_image !=none)
 {
      move_uploaded_file($_files['user_image']['tmp_name'], $path);
      {
          echo "Successful<BR/>"; 
          echo "File Name :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['user_image']['name']."<BR/>"; 
          echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['user_image']['size']."<BR/>"; 
          echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['user_image']['type']."<BR/>"; 
          echo "<img src=\"$path\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
      }
}
else
{
   echo "Error";
}
?>
```

**In this my uploading folder is user and i also want to know that what is the file name after being uploaded as i want to show it to users so how can I do so. Thanks in advance!
If you need more information ask me.**

Comment: the html form looks ok but the PHP script looks confusing. for example, where is the '$user_image' variable defined?, what is the meaning of the constant 'none'?

Comment: $http_post_files is deprecated use $FILES['user_image']['name'] instead

Comment: Are you getting any errors returned?  Does your upload location have proper permissions (chmod 755 or 777) set?

Comment: just try to follow the steps as mention in following links

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @darshan.dodiya hey i got the script working from there but i also want to rename its name can you tell me how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

HTML form do as usual,

Below the coding will automatically create a new folder number based on generation, inside the folder there it will consist the upload. If you want to change the path of the upload, Use \ INSTEAD of / because it will cause error.

**Register.php**

```
 if ($_POST['doRegister'] == "Register")
{

    $path1 = "C:\Uploads\ ";
    if (file_exists($path1))
    {
    $path = $path1 .time().uniqid(rand()).'\ ';


$target_path = $path . basename( $_FILES['user_image']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "Successfully uploaded on $path".$_FILES['user_image']['name']."<br>";

    echo "File Name :".$_FILES['user_image']['name']."<BR/>"; 
          echo "File Size :".$_FILES['user_image']['size']."<BR/>"; 
          echo "File Type :".$_FILES['user_image']['type']."<BR/>"; 
}
    }
else
{

    mkdir($path1);
    $path = $path1 .time().uniqid(rand()).'\ ';
mkdir($path);

$target_path = $path . basename( $_FILES['user_image']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "Successfully uploaded on $path".$_FILES['user_image']['name']."<br>";

    echo "File Name :".$_FILES['user_image']['name']."<BR/>"; 
          echo "File Size :".$_FILES['user_image']['size']."<BR/>"; 
          echo "File Type :".$_FILES['user_image']['type']."<BR/>"; 
}

}   

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


if(isset($_FILES['user_image']))
{ 
 $path = "user/".time().uniqid(rand()).basename($_FILES['user_image']['name'],'.');

  move_uploaded_file($_files['user_image']['tmp_name'], $path);
  {
      echo "Successful<BR/>"; 
      echo "File Name :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['user_image']['name']."<BR/>"; 
      echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['user_image']['size']."<BR/>"; 
      echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['user_image']['type']."<BR/>"; 
      echo "<img src=\"$path\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
  }
}
else
{
  echo "No File Chosen";
}
?>
```